# IntelliJ IDEA: Shortcut for moving to dialog editor that appears in 'Find in Path'

Tags: intellij-idea

Does 'Find in Path' dialog have a shortcut for moving to the editor that appears straight under the list of find results?

[image]

Comment: After i select file, i'm wanna edit its without closing search results window and use for it only a keyboard
https://prnt.sc/sucdkf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No shortcut at the moment. Please vote for [IDEA-230848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230848).

Comment: it's not that i find!
that keys need to press to start edit a file in code preview that placed in bottom of 'Find in Path' dialog?

Comment: Окно ['Find in Path'](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html) вызывается командой `Ctrl+Shift+F` и используется исключительно для поиска текста в большом кол-ве файлов разом. Вы не можете заставить определенный файл открыться в этом окне кроме как способом, описанным мной выше.

Comment: в окне "Find in path" внизу есть окно с кодом при клике ЛКМ в нем можно редактировать код. я хочу переключиться на редактирование кода в нём при помощи горячих клавиш.

Comment: Теперь понятно, благодарю. Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [IDEA-230848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230848)